# Keycloak : authenticating a Rest API written in JAVA

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, keycloak

I'd like to authenticate a Rest service (RS) against a Keycloak server (KS).

RS is accessed via an application (APP) and not a browser for example.

So far, I've understood the way to proceed is as following:

1. APP is authenticating against KS and get an ACCESS_TOKEN.
2. APP is sending a request to the RS passing somehow the ACCESS_TOKEN.
3. RS is extracting the ACCESS_TOKEN and validate / decode it to get the required information associated with the user.

I've hard time finding the right JAVA API to perform the step (3).

So far, I've "verified" the token using a TokenVerifier (setup using the RSA public key of the KS) => TokenVerifier.verify(). Once verified, I'm parsing it to decode it using. So far so good.

One extra step I'd like to achieve is ensuring the ACCESS_TOKEN is still valid in KS. But I did not find any JAVA API for that purpose. So instead, I've issued a regular HTTP request to the UserInfo endpoint using the ACCESS_TOKEN.

So is there any JAVA API to check the validity of the ACCESS_TOKEN ?

Am I doing the thing right for this kind of scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

You can either validate access token by calling the Introspection Endpoint or locally validate it by using [auth0](https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt) library.

More information in keycloak [docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#validating-access-tokens)